# Automatically Log Out UserX when visiting WooCommerceStore

Tags: cookies, logout

I developed a Web-Plattform, and Users Log into a DemoUser in order to Check-Out the Dashboard functionality.

Now the problem  is, that once they are happy with what they see and visit the woocommerce store - they are still logged in and would buy the service as DemoUser.

This seems to be a quiet unique issues, because even though I spent hours on research .. I am barely a step closer to a solution.

How can i log out the Demoaccount once the User visits the Woocommerce-Store?

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of the actions that occur after `parse_query`, because then the variables on which the conditional tags are based are set. Such action can be [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect). The [conditional tag](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) will allow you to check if the current page is a store page. To log out the user, use the [`wp_logout()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout) function.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'se344334_logout_demo_user', 9);

function se344334_logout_demo_user()
{
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    $curr_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( 'DemoUser' == $curr_user->user_login  &&
         (is_woocommerce() || is_checkout() || is_cart()) )
    {
        // destroy user "session"
        wp_logout();

        // redirect to current page after 
        wp_redirect( home_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) );
        die();
    }
}
```